# Want to embed a pdf in my html webpage. It is showing perfectly in laptop's browser but in mobile's browser it is downloading instead of opening

Tags: html, pdf

This is my code which I have used.

```
<html>
<body>
    <object width="400" height="400" data="pdf/1.pdf" type="application/pdf><embed src="pdf/1.pdf" type="application/pdf" /></object>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most popular mobile browsers don't natively support opening PDF files in embedded mode. The file gets downloaded instead, which is what you seem to be experiencing.

One possible workaround is to use the Google Docs Viewer. You can do that by passing the URL of your PDF into the query string for the Google Docs Viewer:

```
https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://link-to-your-pdf-file
```

If you want to do this only on mobile browsers, you could add a piece of JavaScript to check the user agent string:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
   || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
   || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
   || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
   || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
   || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
   || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ) {
    // use the Google Docs Viewer URL
} else {
    // use the regular URL
}
```

Another approach might be to use a JS library like PDFJs: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Answer (score 0):

i think you should really consider opening it in google docs

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://path.com/to/your/pdf.pdf&embedded=true" 
style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```